# Programación PHP con sumas de rangos

Tags: php

Dados dos números introducidos por teclado, realizaremos la suma del rango comprendido entre ellos. Tendremos en cuenta:

· El primer número introducido debe ser menor que el segundo, en su defecto mostrará un mensaje de error realizando una advertencia, permitirá una nueva inserción de los números. En definitiva, validaremos los datos.

· Utilizaremos un bucle FOR, para el recorrido del rango.

· La salida será lo más parecida posible a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de PHP, pero al ejecutarlo no me hace nada:

```
<?php
        $i=0; $n=0; $s=0;


        if (isset($_POST["btnCalcular"])) {
            $n=(int)$_POST["txtn"];

            for ($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++) { 
                 $s=$s+$i;
                    //0=0+1
                }
            }
            
?>
```

Este es el código del formulario html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Suma de rangos</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="fsum.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>ESTE EJERCICIO REALIZA LA SUMA DE LOS NUMEROS COMPRENDIDOS ENTRE EL NUMERO</strong></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Introduce el numero 1:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="txtn" type="text" class="TextoFondo" id="txtn" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Introduce el numero 2:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="txtn" type="text" class="TextoFondo" id="txtn"  />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input name="btnCalcular" type="submit" id="btnCalcular" value="Sumar Rango">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para que veas que hace algo, te faltaría un `echo $s;` al fina. Una vez hecho esto, te darás cuenta que siempre empieza en `1`, por lo que deberías hacer algo similar a lo que has hecho con `$n`. Pon el código del formulario para decirte cómo se llama el campo donde envías el inicio

Comment: ¡Hola David! Gracias por contestar. Acabo de poner el código html del formulario en el post original ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemas con las variables utilizadas, debes identificarlas para el archivo php, a su vez, las condiciones en el for no son las correctas, debes iniciar en el primer número y sumar hasta llegar al segundo número.

suma2.php

```
<?php
    $i=0; $n=0; $s=0;

    if (isset($_POST["btnCalcular"])) {
        $n1=(int)$_POST["num1"];
        $n2=(int)$_POST["num2"];

        for ($i=$n1;$i<=$n2;$i++) { 
             $s=$s+$i;
                //0=0+1
            }
        }
    echo "La suma del intervalo [".$n1." ".$n2."] es ".$s;
```

fsuma.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Suma de rangos</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="suma2.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>ESTE EJERCICIO REALIZA LA SUMA DE LOS NUMEROS COMPRENDIDOS ENTRE EL NUMERO</strong></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Introduce el numero 1:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="num1" type="text" class="TextoFondo" id="num1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Introduce el numero 2:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="num2" type="text" class="TextoFondo" id="num2"  />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input name="btnCalcular" type="submit" id="btnCalcular" value="Sumar Rango">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Marcelo, ¡muchísimas gracias! ¡Solucionado! Solo falta lo de que te muestre el mensaje de error si el primer número introducido debe ser menor que el segundo.

Comment: `if($n1>$n2) echo 'ERROR';` [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)